# Real time update with Angular and Socket

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, real-time

I have a problem with my current implementation of real time with Angular and Socket.io.

- I have a model in Angular and I watch it for modification with $scope.$watch().
- When I detect a modification I send a message with socket to my server.
- When my server detect a call on this update, I save the modification and I send to other user the modification
- Other users are notified about someone modification.

But, I have a problem with this implementation :

- User A update a field
- Send message to server
- Save to the server
- Update notification send to users
- User B is notified
- User B model is updated
- The watch detect a modification in model of User B and send notification
- Send message to server
- Save to the server
- etc...

So, my question is, how to avoid this infinite loop and infinite update ?

Comment: Perhaps you can find useful this example, showing real-time updates displayed by Angular and received from Lightstreamer (instead of Socket.io).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define on the client side a variable named **changed_elsewhere**. The default value of **changed_elsewhere** it's false.

When you receive on your socket a new value from the server, then set **changed_elsewhere** to true. Then, on the watcher, send the new changed value to the server only if **changed_elsewhere** is false. If **changed_elsewhere** is true, then you know that the value has already been on the server and you don't need to send it again.

Finally, your watcher should look this way: if **changed_elsewhere** is true, then turn **changed_elsewhere** to false and don't do nothing; if **changed_elsewhere** is false, then send the new value to the server.

Sorry if the **changed_elsewhere** name is not very suggestive, but i hope that you get my idea.

Comment: Ok, I tested this solution, but with a variable with the value returned by the server (not only true/false), and in my watch, if the value in this variable is equal to my new value, I do nothing ! And seems to works. Thanks for the trick !

Answer (score 0):

Why not create two models? one that is synced from the server and one that is watched for changes. Instead of adding them directly to the controller's scope you create a service which presents it to the controller as one model but behind the scenes it manages the differences?

Comment: I have not tested your solution, but seems a good idea but a little restrictive in my case. I have an object with several attributes and I have a watch on each attribute. Duplicate the model (which can be very heavy in my case) is not the best idea in my case. But thanks for the trick